# How to deny switch-case running unless variable initialized

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement

I'm creating a very basic login system to test switch-case, however I have run into a problem where case 2 cannot run unless a variable is initialized. In my programme case 1 is creating an account, case 2 is logging into the account. However, case 2 can be accessed straight away but will not run unless details from the account have been created. I am looking for a way to deny access to case 2 UNLESS case 1 has firstly been completed. Is this possible? Here is my login system as it stands;

```
public class User {

private static Scanner in;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int userChoice;

    boolean quit = false;

    do {

        System.out.println("1. Create Account");

        System.out.println("2. Login");

        System.out.print("3. Quit");

        userChoice = in.nextInt();

        switch (userChoice) {

        case 1:

            String firstName;
            String secondName;
            String email;
            String username;
            String password;

            System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");

            firstName = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter your second name:");

            secondName = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter your email address:");

            email = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter chosen username:");

            username = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter chosen password:");

            password = in.nextLine();

            break;

        case 2:

            String enteredUsername;
            String enteredPassword;

            System.out.print("Enter Username:");

            enteredUsername = in.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter Password:");

            enteredPassword = in.nextLine();

            if (enteredUsername == username && enteredPassword == password) {

                System.out.println("Login Successfull!");
            }

            else

                System.out.println("Login Failed!");

            break;

        case 3:

            quit = true;

            break;

        default:

            System.out.println("Wrong choice.");

            break;

        }

        System.out.println();

    } while (!quit);

    System.out.println("Bye!");

  }
}
```

I am currently given this error;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The local variable username may not have been initialized
The local variable password may not have been initialized

at User.main(User.java:68)
```

Comment: What happens if the user types 2 first?

Comment: A login attempt could be made, but user would not have login credentials.

Comment: First thing to do: don't try to run your code until it compiles!

Comment: This code confuses me... Why not change it to an if...else if... statement with a boolean controlling if they have created an account.

Comment: Variable to record "case 1" has been run and an `if` statement to prevent "case 2" if it hasn't? Does this seriously need to be a stack overflow question?

Comment: @Yaz Yes, but if the user types 2 first, then `username` and `password` haven't been initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to declare your account variables outside the `while` loop because otherwise they will be re-initialized every time the `while` loop runs.

Second, you can manually initialize the variables to `null` first and then check for that in case 2.

Finally, you are mixing the usage of `nextInt()` and `nextLine()` which will cause some strange UI problems with the Scanner. Here is a corrected version.

Also do not compare String using ==.

```
import java.util.*;

public class User {
    private static Scanner in;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int userChoice;

        boolean quit = false;
        String firstName = null;
        String secondName = null;
        String email = null;
        String username = null;
        String password = null;

        do {

            System.out.println("1. Create Account");
            System.out.println("2. Login");
            System.out.println("3. Quit");
            userChoice = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

            switch (userChoice) {

                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
                    firstName = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter your second name:");
                    secondName = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter your email address:");
                    email = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter chosen username:");
                    username = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter chosen password:");
                    password = in.nextLine();

                    break;

                case 2:

                    String enteredUsername;
                    String enteredPassword;

                    System.out.print("Enter Username:");
                    enteredUsername = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter Password:");
                    enteredPassword = in.nextLine();
                    if (username != null && password != null && enteredUsername.equals ( username) && enteredPassword.equals (password))
                        System.out.println("Login Successfull!");
                    else
                        System.out.println("Login Failed!");

                    break;

                case 3:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Wrong choice.");
                    break;
            }

            System.out.println();

        } while (!quit);

        System.out.println("Bye!");

    }
}
```

Comment: And finally finally, don't compare the username and password with ==, but with enteredusername.equals(username) && entered password.equals(password), otherwise I forsee another StackOverflow question very shortly !

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with scope.

So you have:

```
case 1:

    String firstName;
    String secondName;
    String email;
    String username;
    String password;
```

The problem is, case 2: can't see the username in case 1: as it can't get at it.  So you should declare these at before the switch statement so your code reads something like this:

```
do {

        System.out.println("1. Create Account");

        System.out.println("2. Login");

        System.out.print("3. Quit");

        userChoice = in.nextInt();
        String firstName ="";
        String secondName ="";
        String email ="";
        String username ="";


        String password ="";

        switch (userChoice) {
    case 1:
```

You'll notice I've added an = "" to the string as well, as you should always initialise them even if they're empty.

The strings are now declared outside of the switch statement so they can be accessed by everything within the switch statement now.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler says, you need to initialize a local variable, but the main problem is that you must declare these variables outside of the switch block. And initialize it at least null or "".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class User {

private static Scanner in;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int userChoice;

    boolean quit = false;

    do {

        System.out.println("1. Create Account");

        System.out.println("2. Login");

        System.out.print("3. Quit");

        userChoice = in.nextInt();

        String username = null;  // MOVE HERE -------------
        String password = null;

        switch (userChoice) {

        case 1:

            String firstName;
            String secondName;
            String email;

            System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");

            firstName = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter your second name:");

            secondName = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter your email address:");

            email = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter chosen username:");

            username = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter chosen password:");

            password = in.nextLine();

            break;

        case 2:

            String enteredUsername;
            String enteredPassword;

            System.out.print("Enter Username:");

            enteredUsername = in.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter Password:");

            enteredPassword = in.nextLine();

            if (enteredUsername == username && enteredPassword == password) {

                System.out.println("Login Successfull!");
            }

            else

                System.out.println("Login Failed!");

            break;

        case 3:

            quit = true;

            break;

        default:

            System.out.println("Wrong choice.");

            break;

        }

        System.out.println();

    } while (!quit);

    System.out.println("Bye!");

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code. Declaring the variables outside switch will work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class User {

private static Scanner in;

public static void main(String[] args) {

in = new Scanner(System.in);

int userChoice;

boolean quit = false;

String firstName = null;
String secondName = null;
String email = null;
String username = null;
String password = null;

String enteredUsername = null;
String enteredPassword = null;

do {

    System.out.println("1. Create Account");

    System.out.println("2. Login");

    System.out.print("3. Quit");

    userChoice = in.nextInt();

    switch (userChoice) {

    case 1:

        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");

        do {
            firstName = in.nextLine();               

        }while(firstName == null || firstName.equals(""));


        System.out.println("Enter your second name:");

        secondName = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your email address:");

        email = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter chosen username:");

        username = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter chosen password:");

        password = in.nextLine();

        break;

    case 2:
        System.out.print("Enter Username:");

        do {
            enteredUsername = in.nextLine();                

        }while(enteredUsername == null || enteredUsername.equals(""));

        System.out.print("Enter Password:");

        enteredPassword = in.nextLine();

        if (enteredUsername.equals(username) && enteredPassword.equals(password)) {

            System.out.println("Login Successfull!");
        }

        else

            System.out.println("Login Failed!");

        break;

    case 3:

        quit = true;

        break;

    default:

        System.out.println("Wrong choice.");

        break;

    }

    System.out.println();

} while (!quit);

System.out.println("Bye!");

 }
}
```